# Force Azure Publish to create empty folder

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service

I use Azure websites and my project must have an empty folder on the server. When I publish the project from the Solution Explorer (VS 2013), I don't get it created on the server.

For now, I keep an empty file there to force the creation but I was wondering if there is a proper way to make the publish process create it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are WebDeploy from VS to publish your site, I think the only way to force creating a folder is to have it on your client side. If you use kudu you can look at [post deployment actions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks)

I would suggest updating your code though to create the folder if it doesn't exist. That would make your code more robust and self contained rather than depending on a certain deployment mechanism to create the folder for you.